# What is the best directory structure for building multiple Polymer components?

Tags: polymer, bower

I'm building multiple polymer components to be used across multiple projects. They each have their own git repo. Some of them are dependencies of others. Currently I have each one cloned into a "components" directory. This is problematic though. If I run `bower install` so I can access a functioning demo page without committing, pushing, and bower-updating, other components like `Polymer/paper-button` are installed at the same level per the `.bowerrc` file. I then have source and consumption component directories intermingled. Also, my own components are re-fetched from github (perhaps only sometimes?) and overwrite the directory that contained the `.git` directory.

What is the best way to organize my components and still be able to access the demo page as I make changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend following the guidelines outlined at the start of https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/reusableelements.html for each of your individual elements.

I.e. for each element you're developing, create a fresh top level directory, then place your clone of `<seed-element>` into that, and use the `.bowerrc` that comes with `<seed-element>` and specifies `"directory": "../"`.

List each element's dependencies in each element's `bower.json` and pull them in directly from GitHub. If you're working on your `<element-one>` and it depends on some updates to your `<element-two>` that you can't yet push out to GitHub, then I don't see a problem with just temporarily overwriting the bower-installed version with a local copy of your in-progress `<element-two>` code.

Comment: Thank you. Manually creating a parent directory was the step I was missing. It makes perfect sense. Each component should be isolated in its own parent directory and install its own copies of its dependencies (duh!).